# VS Code and snap apps in ubuntu are not working after downgrading openssl version

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, openssl, downgrade, snap

i downgraded the version of openssl from version 3.0 to 1.1 to solve some issues. For that I first uninstall the openssl and then install the specific version again.
After that, many of the apps were destroyed including the chrome and snap apps. Now the VS code is  not working and other snap apps too.

I uninstalled the code and install it again. It was installed successfuly but when I go into some directory and run the command "code .". It gives me the following error.

`/snap/code/146/usr/share/code/bin/code: 62: /snap/code/146/usr/share/code/bin/../code: not found`

If i try to install it again, using the command
`sudo snap install code --classic`
I get the following response.
`snap "code" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'`

can someone help me with the issue?
Thankyou.

I uninstalled the code and install it again. It was installed successfuly but when I go into some directory and run the command "code .". It gives me the following error.

`/snap/code/146/usr/share/code/bin/code: 62: /snap/code/146/usr/share/code/bin/../code: not found`

If i try to install it again, using the command
`sudo snap install code --classic`
I get the following response.
`snap "code" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'`

Comment: *i downgraded the version of openssl from version 3.0 to 1.1 to solve some issues.*  **How** did you do that? What commands did you use?  What steps did you follow? Where you following some misguided link?  If so, what link?  Did you remove the OpenSSL packages provided by Ubuntu and put OpenSSL 1.1.1 binaries such as `openssl` and `libssl.so` into locations such as `/usr/bin/openssl`?  If so, you've pretty much broken your OS installation.  If you're lucky, you'll be able to reinstall the original Ubuntu OpenSSL packages and hopefully fix things. With more details, you'll get better help.

Comment: Actaully I want to install ruby with rvm, for that there was an issue "_rvm_make-j4". To resolve that issue, I downgraded the openssl version. 
I use the command "sudo apt-get remove --purge openssl libssl-dev". After that it unistalled many packages, I went to log file and reinstall all the pacakges, then install openssl 1.1.1 and lidss-dev.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.